# ATD (after the deadline) for python 3.6 unable to install

Tags: python, pip

When using `sudo pip3 install atd` to try and download the "after the deadline" module `atd` for python 3.6 I get the following error:

```
Failed to build atd
Installing collected packages: atd
Running setup.py install for atd ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tfcxr6us/atd/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xsek23ca-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/atd
copying atd/__init__.py -> build/lib/atd
copying atd/atd.py -> build/lib/atd
running build_scripts
creating build/scripts-3.6
error: file '/tmp/pip-build-tfcxr6us/atd/bin\atddir.py' does not exist
----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tfcxr6us/atd/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xsek23ca-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tfcxr6us/atd/
```

Answer (score 0):

The package [atd](https://pypi.org/project/atd/) is a connector for McAfee ATD API. Is it what you want?

The package is outdated because its `setup.py` uses `ez_setup`, deprecated and removed from `setuptools` long ago. The package was not updated since 2015.

The package is only for windows as its `setup.py` declares a script `bin\\atddir.py`.

I'm sure the module is unusable. Perhaps it's not what you want. What "after the deadline" module are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the response the one i am looking for is this one : https://bitbucket.org/miguelventura/after_the_deadline/wiki/Home

it is a grammar checker

Comment: Is there no way to do it on Linux 

Comment: That's a completely different `atd`. It doesn't have packages at PyPI at all. It even doesn't have `setup.py` and also quite old (2010). Try to [download](https://bitbucket.org/miguelventura/after_the_deadline/downloads/?tab=branches) one of the branches. For Python 3 you need `python3` branch; downloads are at the right column. Download, unpack and copy to `site-packages` manually.